# How to fill red rectangle on image with white background

Tags: r, image, plot, polygon

Trying to plot a red rectangle on image with white background without masking the letters.Please see below Figure 1. How can I make it like Figure 2? I tried alpha, and it looks like Figure 3 which is not as darker as Figure 2. Any suggestion? I am working on R.

THANKS.

```
 img <- readPNG("test.png")
      width<-dim(img)[2]
      height<-dim(img)[1]

  imgNamePlot<-paste("testPlot","png",sep='_EE.')
  png(imgNamePlot, width = width, height = height, res=300)
  op=par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
  plot(c(0, width), c(0, height), type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "",xaxs = "i",yaxs = "i")
  rasterImage(img, 0, 0, width, height, interpolate = F)

  image <- as.raster(rgb(255, 0,  0, 255, maxColorValue = 255))
  geneWidth<-46
  geneHeight<-17
  geneX<-188
  geneY<-519
  rasterImage(image, geneX-0.5*geneWidth+1, height-geneY-0.5*geneHeight-1,               geneX-0.5*geneWidth+geneWidth+1, height-geneY-0.5*geneHeight+geneHeight-1,              interpolate=FALSE)  

  dev.off()
```

[image: Figure 1:My plot]

[image: Figure 2:How can I plot red rectange without mask the font?]

[image: Figure 3: plot with alpha]

Comment: I haven't actually tried anything but I think what you do is adding a color (red rectangle) at the top of your original picture. But in figure 2, they had the colors and write the value on the top of them. I would say you need to find a way to send the rectangle backwards. Looks like an unprofessional comment and indeed it is.

Comment: If you want a darker red, then why are you using `rgb(255,0,0,...)`? Why not `rgb(100,0,0,...)`? Alternatively, using `rmagick` (and therefore ImageMagick) you can [change the white to transparent](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=12619) and then put the red rectangle *under* the raster image by starting with an empty canvas, adding the red, then overlaying the actual raster.

Comment: Any other idea?